# Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document' on mobile site only

Tags: javascript, minify

I'm getting a script error only on my mobile site. On desktop site there is no error and it renders properly.

The error is:

> ```
> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script
> ```
>
> unless it is explicitly opened.

**javascript**

```
function localCurrencyChange(lcfrom, lcvalues, postid) {
    var lcselectname = document.getElementById("lc_currency" + postid);
    var lctoindex = lcselectname.selectedIndex;
    var lcto = lcselectname.options[lctoindex].value;
    localCurrency(lcfrom, lcto, lcvalues, postid);
}

function localCurrencyObject(id, name, symbol) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
var localcurrency_array = new Array();
localcurrency_array['0'] = new localCurrencyObject('USD', 'United States Dollar (USD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['1'] = new localCurrencyObject('GBP', 'British Pound (GBP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['2'] = new localCurrencyObject('EUR', 'Euro (EUR)', '&#8364;');
localcurrency_array['3'] = new localCurrencyObject('AUD', 'Australian Dollar (AUD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['4'] = new localCurrencyObject('CAD', 'Canadian Dollar (CAD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['5'] = new localCurrencyObject('NZD', 'New Zealand Dollar (NZD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['6'] = new localCurrencyObject('CNY', 'Chinese Yuan (CNY)', '&#20803;');
localcurrency_array['7'] = new localCurrencyObject('JPY', 'Japanese Yen (JPY)', '&#165;');
localcurrency_array['8'] = new localCurrencyObject('RUB', 'Russian Rouble (RUB)', '&#1088;&#1091;&#1073;');
localcurrency_array['9'] = new localCurrencyObject('---', '------------------- (---)', '---');
localcurrency_array['10'] = new localCurrencyObject('AFN', 'Afghanistan Afghani (AFN)', '&#1547;');
localcurrency_array['11'] = new localCurrencyObject('ALL', 'Albanian Lek (ALL)', 'Lek');
localcurrency_array['12'] = new localCurrencyObject('DZD', 'Algerian Dinar (DZD)', '&#1583;.&#1580;');
localcurrency_array['13'] = new localCurrencyObject('ARS', 'Argentine Peso (ARS)', '$');
localcurrency_array['14'] = new localCurrencyObject('AMD', 'Armenian Dram (AMD)', '&#1423;');
localcurrency_array['15'] = new localCurrencyObject('AWG', 'Aruba Florin (AWG)', '&#402;');
localcurrency_array['16'] = new localCurrencyObject('AZN', 'Azerbaijan New Manat (AZN)', 'm');
localcurrency_array['17'] = new localCurrencyObject('BSD', 'Bahamian Dollar (BSD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['18'] = new localCurrencyObject('BHD', 'Bahraini Dinar (BHD)', '&#1576;.&#1583;');
localcurrency_array['19'] = new localCurrencyObject('BDT', 'Bangladesh Taka (BDT)', '');
localcurrency_array['20'] = new localCurrencyObject('BBD', 'Barbados Dollar (BBD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['21'] = new localCurrencyObject('BYR', 'Belarus Ruble (BYR)', 'p.');
localcurrency_array['22'] = new localCurrencyObject('BZD', 'Belize Dollar (BZD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['23'] = new localCurrencyObject('BMD', 'Bermuda Dollar (BMD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['24'] = new localCurrencyObject('BTN', 'Bhutan Ngultrum (BTN)', '');
localcurrency_array['25'] = new localCurrencyObject('BOB', 'Bolivian Boliviano (BOB)', '$b');
localcurrency_array['26'] = new localCurrencyObject('BAM', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina Convertible Marka (BAM)', 'KM');
localcurrency_array['27'] = new localCurrencyObject('BWP', 'Botswana Pula (BWP)', 'P');
localcurrency_array['28'] = new localCurrencyObject('BRL', 'Brazilian Real (BRL)', 'R$');
localcurrency_array['29'] = new localCurrencyObject('BND', 'Brunei Dollar (BND)', '$');
localcurrency_array['30'] = new localCurrencyObject('BGN', 'Bulgarian Lev (BGN)', '&#1083;&#1074;');
localcurrency_array['31'] = new localCurrencyObject('BIF', 'Burundi Franc (BIF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['32'] = new localCurrencyObject('KHR', 'Cambodia Riel (KHR)', '&#6107;');
localcurrency_array['33'] = new localCurrencyObject('CVE', 'Cape Verde Escudo (CVE)', '');
localcurrency_array['34'] = new localCurrencyObject('KYD', 'Cayman Islands Dollar (KYD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['35'] = new localCurrencyObject('XOF', 'CFA Franc (BCEAO) (XOF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['36'] = new localCurrencyObject('XAF', 'CFA Franc (BEAC) (XAF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['37'] = new localCurrencyObject('CLP', 'Chilean Peso (CLP)', '$');
localcurrency_array['38'] = new localCurrencyObject('COP', 'Colombian Peso (COP)', '$');
localcurrency_array['39'] = new localCurrencyObject('KMF', 'Comoros Franc (KMF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['40'] = new localCurrencyObject('CDF', 'Congolese franc (CDF)', '');
localcurrency_array['41'] = new localCurrencyObject('CRC', 'Costa Rica Colon (CRC)', '&#8353;');
localcurrency_array['42'] = new localCurrencyObject('HRK', 'Croatian Kuna (HRK)', 'kn');
localcurrency_array['43'] = new localCurrencyObject('CUP', 'Cuban Peso (CUP)', '&#8369;');
localcurrency_array['44'] = new localCurrencyObject('CZK', 'Czech Koruna (CZK)', 'K&#269;');
localcurrency_array['45'] = new localCurrencyObject('DKK', 'Danish Krone (DKK)', 'kr');
localcurrency_array['46'] = new localCurrencyObject('DJF', 'Dijibouti Franc (DJF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['47'] = new localCurrencyObject('DOP', 'Dominican Peso (DOP)', 'RD$');
localcurrency_array['48'] = new localCurrencyObject('XCD', 'East Caribbean Dollar (XCD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['49'] = new localCurrencyObject('EGP', 'Egyptian Pound (EGP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['50'] = new localCurrencyObject('ERN', 'Eritrea Nakfa (ERN)', 'Nfk');
localcurrency_array['51'] = new localCurrencyObject('ETB', 'Ethiopian Birr (ETB)', '');
localcurrency_array['52'] = new localCurrencyObject('FKP', 'Falkland Islands Pound (FKP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['53'] = new localCurrencyObject('FJD', 'Fiji Dollar (FJD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['54'] = new localCurrencyObject('GMD', 'Gambian Dalasi (GMD)', 'D');
localcurrency_array['55'] = new localCurrencyObject('GEL', 'Georgian Lari (GEL)', 'áƒš');
localcurrency_array['56'] = new localCurrencyObject('GHS', 'Ghanian Cedi (GHS)', '&#162;');
localcurrency_array['57'] = new localCurrencyObject('GIP', 'Gibraltar Pound (GIP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['58'] = new localCurrencyObject('GTQ', 'Guatemala Quetzal (GTQ)', 'Q');
localcurrency_array['59'] = new localCurrencyObject('GNF', 'Guinea Franc (GNF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['60'] = new localCurrencyObject('GYD', 'Guyana Dollar (GYD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['61'] = new localCurrencyObject('HTG', 'Haiti Gourde (HTG)', '');
localcurrency_array['62'] = new localCurrencyObject('HNL', 'Honduras Lempira (HNL)', 'L');
localcurrency_array['63'] = new localCurrencyObject('HKD', 'Hong Kong Dollar (HKD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['64'] = new localCurrencyObject('HUF', 'Hungarian Forint (HUF)', 'Ft');
localcurrency_array['65'] = new localCurrencyObject('ISK', 'Iceland Krona (ISK)', 'kr');
localcurrency_array['66'] = new localCurrencyObject('INR', 'Indian Rupee (INR)', '&#8360;');
localcurrency_array['67'] = new localCurrencyObject('IDR', 'Indonesian Rupiah (IDR)', 'Rp');
localcurrency_array['68'] = new localCurrencyObject('IRR', 'Iran Rial (IRR)', '&#65020;');
localcurrency_array['69'] = new localCurrencyObject('IQD', 'Iraqi Dinar (IQD)', '');
localcurrency_array['70'] = new localCurrencyObject('ILS', 'Israeli Shekel (ILS)', '&#8362;');
localcurrency_array['71'] = new localCurrencyObject('JMD', 'Jamaican Dollar (JMD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['72'] = new localCurrencyObject('JOD', 'Jordanian Dinar (JOD)', '&#1583;.&#1575;');
localcurrency_array['73'] = new localCurrencyObject('KZT', 'Kazakhstan Tenge (KZT)', '&#1083;&#1074;');
localcurrency_array['74'] = new localCurrencyObject('KES', 'Kenyan Shilling (KES)', 'Sh');
localcurrency_array['75'] = new localCurrencyObject('KWD', 'Kuwaiti Dinar (KWD)', '&#1583;.&#1603;');
localcurrency_array['76'] = new localCurrencyObject('KGS', 'Kyrgyzstan Som (KGS)', '&#1083;&#1074;');
localcurrency_array['77'] = new localCurrencyObject('LAK', 'Lao Kip (LAK)', '&#8365;');
localcurrency_array['78'] = new localCurrencyObject('LBP', 'Lebanese Pound (LBP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['79'] = new localCurrencyObject('LSL', 'Lesotho Loti (LSL)', '');
localcurrency_array['80'] = new localCurrencyObject('LRD', 'Liberian Dollar (LRD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['81'] = new localCurrencyObject('LYD', 'Libyan Dinar (LYD)', '&#1604;.&#1583;');
localcurrency_array['82'] = new localCurrencyObject('MOP', 'Macau Pataca (MOP)', 'P');
localcurrency_array['83'] = new localCurrencyObject('MKD', 'Macedonian Denar (MKD)', '&#1076;&#1077;&#1085;');
localcurrency_array['84'] = new localCurrencyObject('MWK', 'Malawi Kwacha (MWK)', 'MK');
localcurrency_array['85'] = new localCurrencyObject('MYR', 'Malaysian Ringgit (MYR)', 'RM');
localcurrency_array['86'] = new localCurrencyObject('MVR', 'Maldives Rufiyaa (MVR)', '&#1923;.');
localcurrency_array['87'] = new localCurrencyObject('MRO', 'Mauritania Ougulya (MRO)', 'UM');
localcurrency_array['88'] = new localCurrencyObject('MUR', 'Mauritius Rupee (MUR)', '&#8360;');
localcurrency_array['89'] = new localCurrencyObject('MXN', 'Mexican Peso (MXN)', '$');
localcurrency_array['90'] = new localCurrencyObject('MDL', 'Moldovan Leu (MDL)', '');
localcurrency_array['91'] = new localCurrencyObject('MNT', 'Mongolian Tugrik (MNT)', '&#8366;');
localcurrency_array['92'] = new localCurrencyObject('MAD', 'Moroccan Dirham (MAD)', '&#1583;.&#1605;.');
localcurrency_array['93'] = new localCurrencyObject('MZN', 'Mozambique Metical (MZN)', 'MT');
localcurrency_array['94'] = new localCurrencyObject('MMK', 'Myanmar Kyat (MMK)', '');
localcurrency_array['95'] = new localCurrencyObject('NAD', 'Namibian Dollar (NAD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['96'] = new localCurrencyObject('NPR', 'Nepalese Rupee (NPR)', '&#8360;');
localcurrency_array['97'] = new localCurrencyObject('ANG', 'Neth Antilles Guilder (ANG)', '&#402;');
localcurrency_array['98'] = new localCurrencyObject('NIO', 'Nicaragua Cordoba (NIO)', '$');
localcurrency_array['99'] = new localCurrencyObject('NGN', 'Nigerian Naira (NGN)', '&#8358;');
localcurrency_array['100'] = new localCurrencyObject('KPW', 'North Korean Won (KPW)', '&#8361;');
localcurrency_array['101'] = new localCurrencyObject('NOK', 'Norwegian Krone (NOK)', 'kr');
localcurrency_array['102'] = new localCurrencyObject('OMR', 'Omani Rial (OMR)', '&#1585;.&#1593;.');
localcurrency_array['103'] = new localCurrencyObject('XPF', 'Pacific Franc (XPF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['104'] = new localCurrencyObject('PKR', 'Pakistani Rupee (PKR)', '&#8360;');
localcurrency_array['105'] = new localCurrencyObject('PGK', 'Papua New Guinea Kina (PGK)', 'K');
localcurrency_array['106'] = new localCurrencyObject('PYG', 'Paraguayan Guarani (PYG)', 'Gs');
localcurrency_array['107'] = new localCurrencyObject('PEN', 'Peruvian Nuevo Sol (PEN)', 'S/.');
localcurrency_array['108'] = new localCurrencyObject('PHP', 'Philippine Peso (PHP)', '&#8369;');
localcurrency_array['109'] = new localCurrencyObject('PLN', 'Polish Zloty (PLN)', 'z&#322;');
localcurrency_array['110'] = new localCurrencyObject('QAR', 'Qatar Rial (QAR)', '&#1585;.&#1602;');
localcurrency_array['111'] = new localCurrencyObject('RON', 'Romanian New Leu (RON)', 'lei');
localcurrency_array['112'] = new localCurrencyObject('RWF', 'Rwanda Franc (RWF)', 'Fr');
localcurrency_array['113'] = new localCurrencyObject('WST', 'Samoa Tala (WST)', 'T');
localcurrency_array['114'] = new localCurrencyObject('STD', 'Sao Tome Dobra (STD)', 'Db');
localcurrency_array['115'] = new localCurrencyObject('SAR', 'Saudi Arabian Riyal (SAR)', '&#1585;.&#1587;');
localcurrency_array['116'] = new localCurrencyObject('RSD', 'Serbia Dinar (RSD)', '&#1044;&#1080;&#1085;&#46;');
localcurrency_array['117'] = new localCurrencyObject('SCR', 'Seychelles Rupee (SCR)', '&#8360;');
localcurrency_array['118'] = new localCurrencyObject('SLL', 'Sierra Leone Leone (SLL)', 'Le');
localcurrency_array['119'] = new localCurrencyObject('SGD', 'Singapore Dollar (SGD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['120'] = new localCurrencyObject('SBD', 'Solomon Islands Dollar (SBD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['121'] = new localCurrencyObject('SOS', 'Somali Shilling (SOS)', 'S');
localcurrency_array['122'] = new localCurrencyObject('ZAR', 'South African Rand (ZAR)', 'R');
localcurrency_array['123'] = new localCurrencyObject('KRW', 'South Korean Won (KRW)', '&#8361;');
localcurrency_array['124'] = new localCurrencyObject('LKR', 'Sri Lanka Rupee (LKR)', '&#8360;');
localcurrency_array['125'] = new localCurrencyObject('SHP', 'St Helena Pound (SHP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['126'] = new localCurrencyObject('SDG', 'Sudanese Pound (SDG)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['127'] = new localCurrencyObject('SRD', 'Suriname Dollar (SRD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['128'] = new localCurrencyObject('SZL', 'Swaziland Lilageni (SZL)', 'L');
localcurrency_array['129'] = new localCurrencyObject('SEK', 'Swedish Krona (SEK)', 'kr');
localcurrency_array['130'] = new localCurrencyObject('CHF', 'Swiss Franc (CHF)', 'CHF');
localcurrency_array['131'] = new localCurrencyObject('SYP', 'Syrian Pound (SYP)', '&#163;');
localcurrency_array['132'] = new localCurrencyObject('TWD', 'Taiwan Dollar (TWD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['133'] = new localCurrencyObject('TZS', 'Tanzanian Shilling (TZS)', 'Sh');
localcurrency_array['134'] = new localCurrencyObject('THB', 'Thai Baht (THB)', '&#3647;');
localcurrency_array['135'] = new localCurrencyObject('TOP', 'Tonga Pa\'ang (TOP)', '$');
localcurrency_array['136'] = new localCurrencyObject('TTD', 'Trinidad & Tobago Dollar (TTD)', '$');
localcurrency_array['137'] = new localCurrencyObject('TND', 'Tunisian Dinar (TND)', '&#1583;.&#1578;');
localcurrency_array['138'] = new localCurrencyObject('TRY', 'Turkish Lira (TRY)', '&#8378;');
localcurrency_array['139'] = new localCurrencyObject('AED', 'UAE Dirham (AED)', '&#1583;.&#1573;');
localcurrency_array['140'] = new localCurrencyObject('UGX', 'Ugandan Shilling (UGX)', 'Sh');
localcurrency_array['141'] = new localCurrencyObject('UAH', 'Ukraine Hryvnia (UAH)', '&#8372;');
localcurrency_array['142'] = new localCurrencyObject('UYU', 'Uruguayan New Peso (UYU)', '$U');
localcurrency_array['143'] = new localCurrencyObject('UZS', 'Uzbekistan Som (UZS)', '&#1083;&#1074;');
localcurrency_array['144'] = new localCurrencyObject('VUV', 'Vanuatu Vatu (VUV)', 'Vt');
localcurrency_array['145'] = new localCurrencyObject('VEF', 'Venezuelan Bolivar Fuerte (VEF)', 'Bs');
localcurrency_array['146'] = new localCurrencyObject('VND', 'Vietnam Dong (VND)', '&#8363;');
localcurrency_array['147'] = new localCurrencyObject('YER', 'Yemen Riyal (YER)', '&#65020;');
localcurrency_array['148'] = new localCurrencyObject('ZMW', 'Zambian Kwacha (ZMW)', '');

function localCurrencyUserSelection(sitecurrency, usercurrency, postid) {
    document.write('<select style="width:200px" name="lc_currency' + postid + '" id="lc_currency' + postid + '" onchange="localCurrencyChange(\'' + sitecurrency + '\',lcValues' + postid + ',' + postid + ')">');
    for (var i = 0; i <= localcurrency_array.length - 1; i++) {
        document.write('<option value="' + localcurrency_array[i]['id'] + '" ');
        if (usercurrency == localcurrency_array[i]['id']) {
            document.write('selected="selected"');
        }
        document.write('>' + localcurrency_array[i]['name'] + '</option>');
    }
    document.write('</select>');
}
```

Comment: `document.write`is like the evil, you must not use it. If you want to add some content into HTML element use element.innerHTML or DOM methods like `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild`

Comment: Lol... why does it only affect the page when viewed on a mobile site but it works fine on a desktop? Any code modifications to suggest for this?

Comment: yes. If you want to add some content into HTML element use `element.innerHTML` or DOM methods like `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild` - but I guess you've already heard that. You can also add options to a select by creating a `new Option(value, text)` object or `document.createElement("option");` followed by `selectObject.add(option,index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction for your function :

```
function localCurrencyUserSelection(parentElement, sitecurrency, usercurrency, postid) {
    var html = ['<select style="width:200px" name="lc_currency' + postid + '" id="lc_currency' + postid + '" onchange="localCurrencyChange(\'' + sitecurrency + '\',lcValues' + postid + ',' + postid + ')">'];
    for (var i = 0; i <= localcurrency_array.length - 1; i++) {
        html.push('<option value="' + localcurrency_array[i]['id'] + '" ');
        if (usercurrency == localcurrency_array[i]['id']) {
            html.push('selected="selected"');
        }
        html.push('>' + localcurrency_array[i]['name'] + '</option>');
    }
    html.push('</select>');

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = html.join('');
    var newSelect = span.firstChild;
    parentElement.appendChild(newSelect);
}
```

The call of your function

```
     localCurrencyUserSelection(document.getElementById('myDivThanContainsTheSelect'), ....)
```

Comment: this is an impressively ugly way of dynamically creating a `<select>` element. Points for originality, though

Comment: I know, but it's just a quick and dirty function to replace the ugly `document.write`
Not that creating a string of HTML is faster than create DOM elements.

Comment: @ArnaudGueras at least you're not concatenating strings repeatedly. But yes, for the best speed build the select DOM methods, then append, or even use DocumentFragments (or jQuery's appendAll), but that's not necessary with only one element.

Comment: I don't really care about speed - for such snippets it all comes down to fractions of milliseconds difference, so big deal. My problem with creating a massive string then dumping it in as HTML is that it is so fragile - one badly placed quote mark or missing closing tag in future mods could end up rendering the whole thing as junk which then has a snowball effect. Dom methods are much more foolproof that way.